# NDK is not recognizing some LOCAL_LDFLAGS specific flags

Tags: android-ndk

I'm trying to reduce the size of a generated NDK binary by using the next set of flags

```
LOCAL_LDFLAGS := -Wl, --gc-sections, --icf=safe
```

But is outputting the next error

```
arm-linux-androideabi-g++: error: unrecognized command line option '--gc-sections,'
arm-linux-androideabi-g++: error: unrecognized command line option '--icf=safe'
```

Aren't really not supported or I need to choose a different toolchain? I'm using 4.8 (NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION := 4.8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue, in case is of use to other users, here it goes. In fact was a very silly mistake.
LOCAL_LDFLAGS requires that no spaces exist between commands.

So this:

```
LOCAL_LDFLAGS := -Wl, --gc-sections, --icf=safe
```

Becomes this:

```
LOCAL_LDFLAGS := -Wl,--gc-sections,--icf=safe
```